How to make Type that can only have keys from another Type but the keys can have a new value, new keys should throw an error
type Numbers = {
  a: number;
  b: number;
  f: number;
};

type SameKeysWithNeyTypes = SomeThingKeyOf<Numbers> & {
  a: string; 
  b: Date;
  c: null;   // Error here because c is not in Numbers ?
  // Error because f is missing
}

How can I do this?
Basically the keys of the SameKeysWithNeyTypes type are validated from the keys in Numbers but with the possibility of changing their types one by one ?

Is this approach what you're looking for? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz wow this is great! how would you better name SomeThingKeyOf so it's a bit more descriptive from what I wrote?

@jcalz can this work recursively? If there are nested objects or array of objects? the keys of those objects will also be checked ?

You edited the question to expand the scope after I made a suggestion, which isn't cool. Could you please [edit] to remove the "bonus points" so we can answer the question as asked? Let me know how to proceed.

Hii sorry I thought you would want to try that! I edited now!

It's not that I don't want to try it, it's that there are lots of edge cases and you'd have to give a set of test inputs and outputs and the recursive constraint probably wouldn't work so it would change things. Sounds interesting, but it really needs to be a new question.

Like, maaaybe this approach would do it, but that depends quite heavily on exact use cases (arrays, unions, optional, readonly, etc, etc, etc).

You could define it as a generic utility type HasSameKeysAs<T, U> which always evaluates to U, but will complain unless it has exactly the same keys as T:
type HasSameKeysAs<
  T, U extends {
    [P in keyof T | keyof U]: P extends keyof T ? any : never
  }> = U;

This works because U is constrained to a type that depends on both T and U. We map over both the keys of T and the keys of U. Any key which is present in T will be required and allowed to be anything (with any) whereas any key which is present in U but not T will be forced to be the impossible never type, which essentially prohibits it (well, it allows never, but that's unlikely to accidentally show up... at least it didn't for your example use case).
Let's try it:
type SameKeysWithNeyTypes = HasSameKeysAs<Numbers, {
  a: string;
  b: Date;
}> // error!
// Property 'f' is missing in type '{ a: string; b: Date; }' 
// but required in type '{ a: any; b: any; f: any; }'.

type SameKeysWithNeyyTypes = HasSameKeysAs<Numbers, {
  a: string;
  b: Date;
  c: null;
  f: 1;
}> // error!
// Types of property 'c' are incompatible.

type SameKeysWithNeyyyTypes = HasSameKeysAs<Numbers, {
  a: string;
  b: Date;
  f: 1;
}> // okay

Looks good. Missing keys and extra keys cause errors, while a type with exactly the same keys works fine.
Playground link to code
